# User-defined function in master database won't execute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this function called `fn_blah` that resides in the `Master` database of a SQL Server 2000 box. The same function resides in the `master` database of a SQL Server 2008 box. On the SQL Server 2000 box, the function runs just fine under a different database context without specifying the owner (eg. dbo):

```
User OtherDB1;
EXEC fn_blah;
```

But on the SQL Server 2008 box, the above query won't work. What will work is if you change the database context to `master`, then run it like above. Or you run the following:

```
EXEC master.dbo.fn_blah
```

Anyone seen this kind of behavior before? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: **Don't put user objects in master.**  Problem solved!

Comment: There were changes in how the schema and owner are handled going from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2005.  I don't remember them all, but if you were to look at the changes between the two (there should be documentation on Microsoft's web sites somewhere) you should be able to see why it changed, but since you know how to make it work in both, is it really worth the effort?

Comment: Your context is a little confusing. You are saying you are calling a *function* using *EXEC*?

Comment: @Aaron: I meant just running the function w/ a SELECT rather.

Answer (score 5):

The `master` database is a system database that stores all sorts of information about everything else on your server.

When you put user objects into `master`, you may be able to access them without database context.

**This is essentially unintended behavior** - the engine will check for some objects (depending on the object name and the version of SQL Server) in master before checking the current DB context.

This is a really bad idea and not something to design your processes around.  All sorts of issues can arise, not least of which those objects in master getting overwritten when you upgrade or restart your server since master isn't intended to store user objects!

In short, **don't do this!**  Use the three-part-name for your function calls.

Comment: Or use your own utility database instead of master. If you don't want to apply three-part names, you can create a synonym and then reference two-part names. You should never *want* to write one-part names for ANY type of object, IMHO.

Comment: So is there any scope-level permission that can be granted on the function that can make it seen or called upon from any database context without using part names at all?

Comment: @Chinesinho I'm not sure, but I'm telling you that this is a terrible idea.  It can lead to all sorts of issues.  Suppose you have `master.dbo.fn_stuff` and `somedatabase.dbo.fn_stuff`.  If you execute `fn_stuff` with `somedatabase` as  the current context (but without specifying it) you'll run something you didn't expect to run.  Designing processes around this behavior is an antipattern and is to be avoided.

Comment: @JNK: I understand that this is a bad idea, and I even told the devs that...but they just want to get the cold to compile before making any code changes. Stubborn as a mule on a hot Summer day I tell you.  You know if the following schema has been deprecated in SQL2008 - system_function_schema?

Comment: @Chinesinho That's undocumented and unsupported, and doesn't work in 2005+.  The fix here is to fix the code.  If you know the name of the function you can search sys.sql_modules to find where it occurs and then go fix it.

Comment: Finally got the devs to change their code.  Thanks all for the help :)